# Can convergent perturbation series be incorrect for an action linear in the perturbation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory, classical-field-theory, non-perturbative

Non-perturbative effects are common in mathematics. For example, consider the function $$f(g) = e^{-1/g}+ g + \frac{1}{10} g^2$$ and suppose this function is the answer to some math problem. Perturbative methods in powers of $g$ could find the $g$ and $\frac{1}{10} g^2$ terms, but they could not find $e^{-1/g}$, as it has vanishing Taylor expansion about the origin.

---

However, in physics, when one discusses $e^{-1/g}$ effects from e.g. instantons, we might more typically have the following approximate, moral answer:

$$f(g) \approx e^{-1/g} + \sum_{n=0}^N a_n g^n$$
for some finite $N$ at finite $g$, where one has
$$f(g) \sim \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n g^n$$

where the infinite series does not converge but provides an asymptotic, perturbative expansion for $f(g)$.

It is hard to imagine a physics toy model where one has a **convergent** perturbation series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n g^n$ and yet $f(g)$ differs from it by e.g. a nonperturbative $e^{-1/g}$ factor.

To be more specific, I have in mind that the $f(g)$ here is derived from some problem with an action,

$$f(g) = \int dX e^{-S[X, g]}$$

where $X$ is some field.

---

Does there exist an $S$ that is linear in $g$ (i.e. the Lagrangian density is $L = L_0 + gL_{\rm pert}$) such that a perturbation series for $f(g)$ above in powers of $g$ has a nonzero radius of convergence but does not converge to $f(g)$?

---

I crossposted a related problem, restricted to $1d$ integrals, and found the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4290521) in this restricted case. Translating what I wrote there, I found that for $S$ purely real, the answer is **no**, but for $S$ complex, the answer is **yes**. In particular, in the latter case, there exist examples with an infinite radius of convergence (the perturbation series vanishing exactly) and the answer nonzero.

For this question, I would appreciate an answer motivated from physics and perhaps elaborating on the interesting comments to this question.

Comment: there are many examples of SUSY theories where some objects (e.g., a beta function) is zero to all orders in perturbation theory (so, convergent series), but non-zero at the non-perturbative level.

Comment: You might find the keyword "resurgence" (and the literature on it) useful

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks, that's good to know. I'm not very familiar with SUSY, but is it possible that all those theories require the action to be nonlinear in the coupling constant? For example, the wikipedia page for N=4 super Yang-Mills has the coupling constant enter as $1/g^2$, as $g$, and as $g^2$.

Comment: @user196574 that is just a convenient convention, it has nothing to do with N=4 specifically. We often use the same convention for regular Yang-Mills. If you prefer the usual convention just perform the change of variables $A\to g A$, after which $g$ enters linearly (and quadratically), as is standard in textbook QCD.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks! After the transformation, the coupling constant still enters in with two different powers, so it's tempting that the resulting action, which is nonlinear in the coupling, may have fundamental differences relative to actions in which the coupling only enters linearly (which is technically the main focus of this question, but it's good to hear about these examples with the coupling constant entering in multiple powers).